# Right nodejs+express+mongodb application architecture

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm new to nodejs (and js itself) and I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to combine mongodb and express. In some npm-modules I saw a construction, where middleware set a db-property in request object, which contained current database connection. Something like this:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next)) {
    /* creating connection */
    req.db = createdConnection;
    next();
});
```

I find its very convenient to make the whole structure of the project in similar req-modifying manner, for example:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next)) {
    /* lots of requires, which provide necessary functionality */
    req.UsersModule = usersModule;
    req.ArticlesModule = articlesModule;
    /* and so on, plenty of them */
    next();
});
```

But I'm not sure this is a good idea. For example, having non-request-related functionality in request object is semantically awful. More than that, I can't predict could this way break something important in the future or not. Could you help me to resolve such a predicament, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout below on [github](https://github.com/gothinkster/node-express-realworld-example-app)

**node-express-realworld-example-app**

It has handling of following

- authentication
- db access (mongo)
- routes handling
- error handling

Comment: Thank you for the example, it was in some way useful. But it has mongoose, which I haven't planned to use in my project. Besides, I still don't fully understand why changing the request object will hardly be a good practice, which is exactly the reason why I created the question.